# VBScript Query not work in Spanish

Tags: vbscript

Currently I'm working in a VBScript project for update some values in Client's Access database from a csv file. But now I'm getting an error while the script run on clients system (This system in Spanish language), this working fine in my system (english language).

I'm getting an issue while updating a query written in VBScript and the Query is

```
"UPDATE Table1 INNER JOIN tempTable ON Table1.[User ID] = tempTable.userId SET Table1.FechaPagoHasta = STFechaPagoHasta"
```

The issue found in 'FechaPagoHasta' named column in table 'Table1'. This issue only caught when I run script in Clients system (spanish). Any idea about this issue.

Comment: And the issue is .... ? Without more data, all i can suggest is, Have you checked the date format? In spanish systems it is usually dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Yeah, add input data examples, and we´ll see...